# Basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have doubts about whether

\begin{align*}
\left\lbrace \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{-1-i\sqrt{11}}{2} \\
1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{-1+i\sqrt{11}}{2} \\
1
\end{pmatrix}  \right\rbrace 
\end{align*}

is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$. I still do not work with bases for the field of complexes, that is why I have this doubt.

Comment: Over what field? Also, only have one set, so unclear what you mean by "which": it either is or isn't, there aren't any choices to be made.

Comment: Base for $\mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: They are two vectors in a 2-dimensional space. So just check for linear dependence by calculating the determinant and conclude.

Comment: **Basic facts:** In a vector space $V$ over a field $F$, a subset $\{v_1,v_2\} \subset V$ is linearly independent if and only if doesn't exists $a \in F$ such that $av_1 = v_2$. Also, if the space is finite-dimensional, any linearly independent subset of $V$ with $\dim(V)$ vectors is a basis. Does this help you?

Comment: The determinant trick works if you want to show that these two form a basis of $\Bbb{C}^2$ **over the field of complex numbers.** The space $\Bbb{C}^2$ can also be viewed as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$. Then it becomes 4-dimensional, and you need four vectors to have a basis over $\Bbb{R}$, such as $\binom 10$, $\binom i 0$, $\binom 01$, $\binom 0i$, to able to write a general vector as a linear combination:
$$\binom{a+bi}{c+di}=a\binom10+b\binom i0+c\binom01+d\binom0i$$
with $a,b,c,d$ real. As opposed to
$$\binom {z_1}{z_2}=z_1\binom 10+z_2\binom01$$ with $z_1,z_2$ complex.

Comment: (cont'd)  I guess you are at a point in your studies when the distinction between vector spaces over different fields is still unfamiliar territory.

Comment: "Base for $\mathbb{C}^2$". Yes, you said that. I asked **over what field**. It makes a difference. It is two dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$,. but it is **four** dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$ and infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$. You need to specify the field..

Comment: @azif00: Your basic fact needs an addendum: it could be that there is no $a$ with $av_1=v_2$, but there is one with $v_1=av_2$ (if $v_1=0$ but $v_2\neq 0$)...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Check the determinant  of these  vectors, to know  about their independence .You can see they are obviously  linearly independent.
Now for the spanning try  yourself.